# How do I select distinct value and its count from a column?

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I have an application (in C#) where users vote on their favorite fruit (`ProduceID = 1` apples, oranges, bananas), or veggie (`ProduceID = 2` cucumber, potato, squash). In my database (Microsoft SQL 2012 Management System) I have the following columns `Num`, `ProduceID`, `Vote`:

A select all currently will look like:

```
Num|ProduceID|Vote
---------------------
1  |1        |Orange
2  |2        |Potato
3  |1        |Orange
4  |2        |Potato
5  |1        |Banana
```

I want to run a SQL query that would get the distinct votes and their count like this:

```
ProduceID|Vote  |Count
----------------------
1        |Orange|2
2        |Potato|2
3        |Banana|1
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT ProduceID, distinct Vote, Count (Vote) FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

This gives an incorrect syntax error.

Comment: The Distinct keyword comes before all the Select expressions and applies to the whole combination of expressions rather than the column/expression it's defined before. You also miss the Group By clause.

Comment: thanks, giving reasons for downvotes would be nice

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume people did because its not a C# question.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove the tag but I figured it would help to explain better what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why does Banana have the same ProduceID as Orange? Kind of defeats the object of it being an ID / identifier.

Comment: it doesn't....user error when copying it over

Comment: Im gonna agree with Skullomania...the downvotes here are non-nonsensical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   ProduceID, Vote, COUNT (*) 
FROM     [DB].[dbo].[Table]
GROUP BY ProduceID, Vote
```